# What is the purpose of `or None` in this code?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've been browsing the code of `pyparsing` library. In there, I found the following fragment:

```
    result = instring[loc] == self.firstQuoteChar and self.re.match(instring,loc) or None
    if not result:
        raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)

    loc = result.end()
    ret = result.group()
```

To boil this down some more, my understanding of the `result` in there is:

```
result = firstCharacterIsCorrect(...) and self.re.match(...) or None
```

Here is what I don't understand: why have `or None` in there?

If first character is not correct, without `or None` we get `False`. If it is correct, but the regexp fails we get `None` from failed match anyway.

In either case (with False or with None) `if not result` will do the right thing.

So why add `or None`? What am I missing? Why is `None` preferable to `False`?

Comment: As suggested by @MarkTolonen, I tagged the question with [tag:pyparsing] to ask the library's author...

Answer (score 3):

The author wants `result` to be `None` or the match object.  Without `or None`, if the first test fails `result` would be `False` due to short-circuiting rules.

Comment: What I don't understand is - what's wrong with False? The way it's used, False will do just as well. What am I missing?

Comment: @Arkadiy `False` is ambiguous as there are many objects that can be inherently false, e.g. `0`, `[]`, `""`, etc.  `None` is an explicit, non-boolean object with unambiguous meaning for "nothing".

Comment: @pylang hmm... I sort of see your point. But, just for clarity: is there anything in that code fragment that makes None better than False?

Comment: @pylang but in that case, why have the catch-all `if not result` to raise an error, and not check for `None` explicitly? It serves only to raise an exception.

Comment: In the fragment shown, it looks like it won't matter, but the key is "the author wants" :)  You can ask him. Tag your question `pyparsing` and he'll see it. He's active on SO.

Comment: Indeed, duck-typing seems like another option.  It seems `False` would also work, although this principle of returning `None` as a default result is pythonic too (e.g. functions return `None` by default).  I cannot speak for the author's choice of this particular implementation.